# Google visualization - issues with high number of charts on same page

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am having issues displaying a high number of Google Visualization bar charts on the same page. (around 150 charts) 
The charts all render, but in some of them and in a random way, some columns don't get rendered. There is nothing wrong with data as the same code would display correctly if displayed on it's own.

Is there any solution?

The following is the code I have for one of the charts (imagine it replicated by 150)

```
<div id="chart_div_17349_"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages': ['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    $(function () {
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart17349);

        function drawChart17349() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Questions","Employees","Executive Team"],["strongly disagree",1.47,0],["disagree",12.75,0],["don\u2019t know",53.43,12.5],["agree",25.98,75],["strongly agree",6.37,12.5]]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Question',
                hAxis: {title: '', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
                colors: configColors,
            };

                            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_17349_'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Just an advice: _Rather than displaying so many charts in one go, you can render them on some event when demanded by the user, this can improve performance of your page with respect to rendering time_...

Comment: Drawing 150 charts isn't the problem (see [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/cxkj8/)), so I suspect that it is that way you are drawing them that is causing the problem.  Switch your code to use a single `google.load` call and a single `google.setOnLoadCallback` call (that calls a function that calls all of your draw functions).  Remove the draw functions from the jQuery wrappers.  Does that improve things for you?